# How to write a CXF client with implicit security header

Tags: web-services, cxf

I have to access a service which is developed using different framework. The client program is using CXF. I dont have access to the provider environment so I cannot use any config files (Cxf.xml, cxfservlet.xml etc..). I need to access the webservice with implicit security header (UsernameTokenType, oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd) . Can anyone throw some light on this?..

Answer (score 1):

First, read the [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/WS-Security).

After that, for this subject I recommend an email to the CXF User mailing list. After, of course, you check out the Confluence doc. The experts on that issue don't infest Stack Overflow yet.